# Shopify Python API : How to serialize products list to JSON?

Tags: python, json, serialization, shopify, shopify-app

I want to fetch Products list and return as JSON using the Shopify Python API.
I tried the .to_json() function

```
products=shopify.Product.find().to_json()
```

Got the error

```
'PaginatedCollection' object has no attribute 'to_json'
```

I tried doing

```
products=shopify.Product.find()
js=json.dumps(products)
```

Error:

```
Object of type Product is not JSON serializable
```

How can I serialize the Products response to JSON ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to loop through the list,convert each to dict (to_dict() function) and append to a list.

```
products=shopify.Product.find()
productsJSON=[]
for product in products:
    productsJSON.append(product.to_dict())
```

You can now send productsJSON list as a JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting it into the dictionary like this:

```
product=shopify.Product.find(Remote-id of product)
product=shopify.Product.find(124583278)

product_result = product.to_dict()
```